# What are the astrological implications of fasting on saturdays?

Tags: astrology, fasting

I am thinking of fasting on saturdays, but I want to be careful about doing it. If you know the astrological effects of fasting, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a source for this available at the moment, and I don't think you will believe my authority if I tell you what is correct, so I will take you through the whole depth of understanding.

वासरः of शनैश्चर... र is the Agni वास means home/dwelling. So, the Agni for the AhoRaatra is given by Shani.

What is Agni? Agni is the quality of existence (or the tattva) that transforms things. As you read this, symbols in your mind are transformed to meaning because you know the English language, that is Agni. Agni is also the transformation of food into Praana in your intestines. And, so on.

Shani represents दु:ख according to Guru Paraashara's Brhat Paraashara Hora Shastra.

> देवेज्यो ज्ञानसुखदो भृगुर्वीर्यप्रदयकः ।
> ऋषिभिः प्राक्तनैः प्रोक्तश्छायासूनुश्च **दुःखदः** ॥ १३॥ -[3.13 BPHS](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_sociology_astrology/par0110.html)

What is दुःख ? दु means bad/unpleasant. ख means space/sky.
This is the reason ShaniDeva represents work, labor, pain, sadness, (chronic) diseases and so on as they're all linked by दुःख.

### Now, your question, what happens by fasting on Saturdays?

What is fasting? is it दुःख of the body? Yes. Your body's सुख is that you feed it and you keep it still on a sofa 24/7, like the nature of BrhaspatiDeva.

So, what happens, when you use the Agni (energy for every change/transformation) of Shani (दुःख) to produce दुःख in your body? It will simply exhaust the दुःख Agni of Shani through the channel of your body.

Suppose Shani was going to give you Bowel Cancer in 2025. If you do this fasting every Saturday, (with rituals for beginning fasting in Shani hora at sunrise for best effect), he will maybe just give you a little IBS instead.

Why will he do this? Because you have already exhausted part of the दुःख Karma Phala that your body (or life) was pre-decided to suffer, in other words, the Karma balance of ShaniDeva for you has been reduced, so now you will suffer less in your whole life, particularly in relation to Sthira Raashis and the body. There's other better ways to target the दुःख of poverty or work and so on.

Hopefully that's enough to answer the question, I won't be giving any more clarifications as anything over this amount is pretty much supposed to be a secret.

**Remember, that no penance can ever give bad results.** The tri-anga of Tapa is आयुः, प्रयत्नः and कालः. For multiplicatory effects, all 3 need to align. That's why certain Tithis are great, or certain days, or certain months, or certain nakshatras and so on. But, as long as you have a good amount of आयुः (how long you do the penance) and प्रयत्नः (how much effort/pain it takes you to do it), you will get good enough results, even without knowledge of कालः.

The प्रयत्नः depends on your own nature. If you suffer unpleasantness of mind and body at 6 hours of the fast, then that is the moment the fast truly begins, the first 6 hours have (basically) no benefit. Some people can handle 12 hour fasts, others can handle 2 days. If you want a real effect to happen, then I recommend a 24 hour fast without water for okay results, or 12 hour fast without water for minimal results. Anything lesser than that produces no effect (for most people).

Comment: Yes, but if you feel you're in any actual bodily danger and need to eat, then eat. That being said make sure to eat a lot the day before! :)

Comment: I should try this though for sure!!! Any tips?

Comment: Just do a Samkalpa at Shani Hora at sunrise (about how long you will fast and for what benefit), do Shnaischara puja at the same time, if possible, otherwise read a Shani Stotra 8 times. Even better, if both. For max benefits, you can do a homa via agni to Shnaischara, but I imagine, it will be difficult for most.

Also, take a bath at the start, and at the end when you end the fast. Break the fast with some food related to Shainschara. You can look this online for whatever is available to you. @Haridasa

Comment: Will do sir! I am currently studying dharmashastras in full, so I am waiting before spiritual stuff.

Comment: I usually chant 108 times based on the Rajshri Souls Mantra I want to acquire more of Brihaspati's grace I already do like a lot of prayer to him on a weekly-ish basis. I am also interested in Budh. Any way to make these stronger with fasting? Also what benefits does Shani provide specifically?

Comment: 108 is not really needed. That number is used to cover the 12 raashis * 9 grahas, for the most part. 8 is sufficient. More is not always superior (unless you have lots of free time). Just like doing some things on certain tithis magnifies effect, doing some things certain times magnifies effect. To target Shanishchara, 8 is the ideal number. Rajarshi Souls typically has horrendous pronunciations by the way. Also, you can fast on each day, everyday, and just eat once in the evening after sunset. It's pretty Ok as long as you're not involved in manual labor.

Comment: Oh no... Ahh.. umm.. Any trustable pronunciations?

Comment: Here is what I use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0nqvC249UM and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pv_Ha2qE3P8

Comment: As for benefits of Shanischara, you can read stories about him from Puranas. But overall, any sort of material gain (related to work), work itself, chronic pain (mental or physical) and things transferred from past life to current, that were originally gained by hard work is governed by him. Although that may sound like something small, believe me, that covers well over 20% of your whole being, if you think about it and apply it to all areas.

Comment: @Haridasa the anunaaskias haven't been properly used, plus the length of the Maatraas are wrong. It doesn't matter too much since this is a Stotra though. 

As for the second link, it will affect the effect if you go into any depth with the Mantra, the pronunciation there is wrong.

Anyways, you should probably switch to something that is relevant to you. The shanti stotra won't really do much (other than calm the planet down, which is only relevant if he's in a bad nakshatra or raashi or transit). As for the Budha mantra, I don't know the source of it, so I can't comment on the effect.

Comment: Okay thank you, I love both Budh and Brihaspati, I am native to Brihaspati's planet and he allowed me to better understand dharma.

Comment: But for Brihaspati is there a source for stories and prayer.

Comment: @Haridasa there's some instances in Mahabharata